# find position of column string in another column using Pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a Dataframe with 2 columns

```
   col1     col2
1  cat      the cat
2  dog      a nice dog
3  horse    horse is here
```

I need to find the position of each string of col1 in col2.

Solution must be:

```
   col1     col2          col3
1  cat      the cat        4
2  dog      a nice dog     7
3  horse    horse is here  0
```

There must be a simple solution to do this without using painful loops, but i can't find it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### [**`numpy.core.defchararray.find`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.find.html)

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import find

a = df.col2.values.astype(str)
b = df.col1.values.astype(str)
df.assign(col3=find(a, b))

    col1           col2  col3
1    cat        the cat     4
2    dog     a nice dog     7
3  horse  horse is here     0
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I am looking for. Do you know if there is a Pandas equivalent?

Comment: The rough equivalent is `df.col2.str.find('cat')` but it fails to do pair-wise find.

Answer (score 5):

In `pandas` when working with strings, often loops or list comprehensions will be faster than the built-in string methods. In your case, it can be a pretty short one:

```
df['col3'] = [i2.index(i1) for i1,i2 in zip(df.col1,df.col2)]

>>> df
    col1           col2  col3
1    cat        the cat     4
2    dog     a nice dog     7
3  horse  horse is here     0
```

Comment: My DataFrame has 1 million rows and my strings can be 50000 char length. I don't really want to try this. Pandas/Numpy functions are made to speed up this kind of heavy thing

Comment: That's true that generally `pandas` and `numpy` functions are made to speed things up, but in the case of strings, the methods provided often fail to provide speed boosts. I haven't timed it with a big dataframe of large strings in your case, but it may not be as slow as you expect.

Comment: To my surprise, this did run about as the numpy solution on my dataset with 5M entries and string lengths of 1-39 (substrings) and 100-150 (search target).